# Xcode framework, libraries, embedded content icon meanings

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, embedded, icons

I'm using Xcode 14.3 and I don't understand what the different icons mean under **target -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content**.

What does the icon looking like a house mean?

[image]

What does the icon looking like a yellow toolkit mean?

[image]

What does the icon looking like a blue toolkit mean?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In short, the icon looking like a house is `static library`. The yellow toolkit (.framework) is `dynamic library`. And the last one is a kind of framework package. You can read more about .xcframework [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle)

There are a lot of things to figure out about these definitions. That is the keyword, you should research it first.